# How to generate S3 presigned URL using perl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am using the sample from https://github.com/rbrigham/s3-signed-url to generate the S3 presigned url.
When i access the generated url I get below error:

```
 <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>
Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters
</Message>
<RequestId>60F1F4F2EC1B24BB</RequestId>
<HostId>
dhHvqSpTqXn1e01TKXAKV8+pzPZkNKGcuCYEuyYMvViRvLdbxpe2ml9Po66t+tboRMPhClmYQe8=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Can anybody tell me what else I am missing?

I have bucket name containing the dot characters and have to use SSL certificate so I need PATH based s3 url.

Do I need to set any specific permission on my IAM user/s3 bucket? I have all permission on S3(I have aws full admin access iam policy set).

Ex url:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/<object>?Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Expires=1000000%
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell if you made the error when sanitizing the signed URL, but there is a missing `&` before `AWSAccessKeyId` that would explain this error.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for comment, the & was just typo here. I am able to solve this issue with this(https://github.com/gdbtek/aws-tools) bash script. Looks like there was issue with perl api I was using.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this within Perl, use [Amazon::S3::SignedURLGenerator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::S3::SignedURLGenerator)

```
use Amazon::S3::SignedURLGenerator;

my $generator = Amazon::S3::SignedURLGenerator->new(
    aws_access_key_id     => $aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key => $aws_secret_access_key,
    prefix => 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
    expires => 600, # 10 minutes
);

my $url = $generator->generate_url('GET', 'path/file.txt', {});
```